# How to Get Total of a Column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sum

i have a question to do a sum of the column and do something like this:
http://puu.sh/axKnr/12d3b2c2eb.png

I have a query with pivots to put the information by months, but i dont know how to inject the last row and sum the column, i hope anyone can help me.

```
SELECT
  Programador,
  ISNULL([1], 0) AS Enero,
  ISNULL([2], 0) AS Febrero,
  ISNULL([3], 0) AS Marzo,
  ISNULL([4], 0) AS Abril,
  ISNULL([5], 0) AS Mayo,
  ISNULL([6], 0) AS Junio,
  ISNULL([7], 0) AS Julio,
  ISNULL([8], 0) AS Agosto,
  ISNULL([9], 0) AS Septiembre,
  ISNULL([10], 0) AS Octubre,
  ISNULL([11], 0) AS Noviembre, 
  ISNULL([12], 0) AS Diciembre
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      u.Nombre as Programador, 
      MONTH(FechaCreacion) AS Mes, CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(5,1)) as Duracion
  FROM Programaciones p
  INNER JOIN Usuarios u on u.Nombre = p.Programador
  WHERE p.Accion = 'Programada' and u.Rol = 'Programador'
) AS t
PIVOT (
  SUM(Duracion)
  FOR Mes IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as p
ORDER BY p.Programador
```

Comment: That kind of thing is often better in the front-end reporting application ... if you need to artificially force it, you could do the same thing with a UNION ALL but say `...'TOTAL' AS Programador...` ...

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a sub select and then [Group by Grouping sets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx) perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP. You may need to look into grouping_id.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510624%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Or you could use COMPUTE but this returns in a separate grid.

**EDIT:Just reread the documentation on this. `COMPUTE` and `WITH ROLLUP` will be removed in a future version(beyond SQL2014 for with Rollup and beyond 2008r2 for COMPUTE). Use `ROLLUP` instead.**

Using GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP (I think this is the right syntax)

```
SELECT
    Programador,
    SUM(ISNULL([1], 0)) AS Enero,
    SUM(ISNULL([2], 0)) AS Febrero,
    SUM(ISNULL([3], 0)) AS Marzo,
    SUM(ISNULL([4], 0)) AS Abril,
    SUM(ISNULL([5], 0)) AS Mayo,
    SUM(ISNULL([6], 0)) AS Junio,
    SUM(ISNULL([7], 0)) AS Julio,
    SUM(ISNULL([8], 0)) AS Agosto,
    SUM(ISNULL([9], 0)) AS Septiembre,
    SUM(ISNULL([10], 0)) AS Octubre,
    SUM(ISNULL([11], 0)) AS Noviembre, 
    SUM(ISNULL([12], 0)) AS Diciembre,
    GROUPING(Programador) AS 'Grouping'
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      u.Nombre as Programador, 
      MONTH(FechaCreacion) AS Mes, CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(5,1)) as Duracion
  FROM Programaciones p
  INNER JOIN Usuarios u on u.Nombre = p.Programador
  WHERE p.Accion = 'Programada' and u.Rol = 'Programador'
) AS t
PIVOT (
  SUM(Duracion)
  FOR Mes IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as p
GROUP BY Programador with Rollup
ORDER BY p.Programador
```

Using COMPUTE

```
SELECT
  Programador,
  ISNULL([1], 0) AS Enero,
  ISNULL([2], 0) AS Febrero,
  ISNULL([3], 0) AS Marzo,
  ISNULL([4], 0) AS Abril,
  ISNULL([5], 0) AS Mayo,
  ISNULL([6], 0) AS Junio,
  ISNULL([7], 0) AS Julio,
  ISNULL([8], 0) AS Agosto,
  ISNULL([9], 0) AS Septiembre,
  ISNULL([10], 0) AS Octubre,
  ISNULL([11], 0) AS Noviembre, 
  ISNULL([12], 0) AS Diciembre

FROM
(
  SELECT 
      u.Nombre as Programador, 
      MONTH(FechaCreacion) AS Mes, CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.FechaInicio, p.FechaFin) / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(5,1)) as Duracion
  FROM Programaciones p
  INNER JOIN Usuarios u on u.Nombre = p.Programador
  WHERE p.Accion = 'Programada' and u.Rol = 'Programador'
) AS t
PIVOT (
  SUM(Duracion)
  FOR Mes IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as p
ORDER BY p.Programador
COMPUTE SUM(Enero),
SUM(Febrero),
SUM(Marzo),
SUM(Abril),
SUM(Mayo),
SUM(Junio),
SUM(Julio),
SUM(Agosto),
SUM(Septiembre),
SUM(Octubre),
SUM(Noviembre),
SUM(Diciembre)
```

Comment: as @xQbert suggested you may need to wrap it in a subselect

Comment: The first one works and sum all the columns and put the row in the first one was really helpful to me

Comment: glad you got your answer. For the compute example I left the grouping column in the compute example...bad copy paste error. i fixed it so it might work now.

Comment: @Oliver - Slick! Wasn't aware of that keyword before.